# Methods does not work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating an Ionic 2 app and I want to create some methods in the `.ts` file.
In the `.html` file I called a function but it does not work.
this is very basic, just for testing but won't work.
This is the `.html` file:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="background-card-page">

  <ion-card onclick="showInfo()">
    <div class="imageContainer">
      <img src="assets/img/placeholder.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card-title" id="title">São Paulo</div>
    <div class="card-subtitle">41 Listings</div>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

this is the `.ts` file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  /**
   * showInfo
   */
  public showInfo() {
    console.log("Hello.");
  }
}
```

Comment: The syntax is `(click)="showInfo()"`. This is indeed basic stuff. Read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I did, still didn't work, I can't see anything on the console.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add 'clickable' for the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace onclick="showInfo()" with (click)="showInfo()".

Comment: Thanks, I changed it, but still can't see any output.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to add 'clickable' for the card.